# Jquery If condition True add style visibility:hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying, if an "if" condition is true, to set the style of an element to "visibility:hide;".

I've done this:

```
if (user.privilege = 3) {
        $("#persone").css("visibility:hidden;");
}
```

But when the If condition runs, in the console i get this error:

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')"

What should i do to solve this?

```
var html = '<div class= "col-lg-6">'+
           '<label class="mt-15">A chi è riferito l\'evento? </label>' +
                 '<select class="form-control" id="persone" >' +
                    _this.GetOptionPersone() +
                 '</select >' +
           '</div>' ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a couple of syntax issues. Firstly `=` is for assignment. To compare values you need to use `==` or `===`.

Secondly `css()` accepts 2 arguments, the rule name and its value, and it shouldn't have the trailing `;`.

```
if (user.privilege == 3) {
  $("#persone").css('visibility', 'hidden');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, now I don't get the error any ore, but, even if the condition is True and My program uses it, it doesn't hide the element...

Comment: In that case there's likely an issue in your HTML or CSS. If you edit the question to include an example of them we may be able to help

Comment: The (main) problem probably comes from that there is no element with `#persone`

Comment: That code works in isolation: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/q2zpnshw/. Do you have more than one element in the DOM with `id="persone"`?

Comment: Ahhh, im dumb. I just realized that at the moment when the if start, the html code still isn't showing. I just have to move the if condition lower in the code... Sorry for wasting time